NiFi Parameters Not Loading from Custom Properties File
I am new to nifi and professional development in general and I'm trying to load parameters into Apache NiFi from a custom properties file, but they aren't appearing in the NiFi UI after a restart.
I've added my parameters to a custom.properties file in the conf directory as such:
context1.parameter1=8a2Hc12

and updated the nifi.properties file trying both
nifi.parameters.file=./conf/custom.properties

And
nifi.variable.registry.properties=./conf/custom.properties

Despite this, the parameters don't show up. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?
My setup:
NiFi version: 2.0.0
Operating System: Windows 11
Any help would be appreciated!
